# Search for data that matches every single tag (using the LIKE operator)

Tags: sql, relational-division

For the past two days I've been doing my best to put together a query that will pull data based on inputted tags. The purpose is for an autocomplete field, where the words the user inputs are split into tags. I really need to use the LIKE operator because the whole purpose of autocomplete is that the user does not need to write out full words

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `tag` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `mid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `mid` (`mid`),
  KEY `alphabetizer` (`tag`),
  CONSTRAINT `tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`mid`) REFERENCES `movies` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Current query:

```
SELECT *
    FROM movies ,
    JOIN tags t ON m.id = t.mid
   WHERE t.tag LIKE 'Dawn%' OR t.tag LIKE 'of%'
GROUP BY m.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.tag) = 2
```

EDIT: The issue is that, as more tags are added, the vaguer the results get. This is the opposite effect.

Comment: What would be the representation form for a `list of tags`?  Can it be a table?

Comment: You don't need that `group by` and `having`

Comment: @Rahul I've made some edits, please check again and confirm.

Comment: @PM77-1 Each tag has its own row in a table called "tags".

Comment: Instead so much of description, try posting table structure for movies and tags along with some sample data (OR) a sqlfiddle(http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: Let say, you want to find a movie that matches 10 tags.  How would your script know which tags you are interested in? How would these 10 tags be stored and where?  For example, will they be stored in a small **Tags to search for** table?

Comment: @PM77-1, exactly, that's the question; nice point. plumbing a list of `like 'x%' and like '%y' and ....` is awful.

Comment: `group by` not needed cause I don't see you are doing any aggregation at all.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the post. Does this help some? I really need to use the LIKE operator because the whole purpose of autocomplete is that the user does not need to write out full words.

Comment: Please stop feeding us your requirements one spoon at a time.  Think your entire task through and then produce an unambiguous and coherent description.

Comment: @PM77-1 Sorry. I didn't expect so much traffic at once. This should be all you need to know now.

Comment: **Where** and **how** this partial tags are going to be stored.  You've been ignoring this issue so far.  I assume that in will not be always 2 tags that you need to match.

Comment: @PM77-1 Each movie title is split() where there are spaces. Each object in the resulting array is stored as a lowercased tag, with a foreign key linked to the movie ID the tags were made from.

Comment: I give up. Apparently you have in mind a `PHP` (or other front-end) component that will dynamically build your query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58037/discussion-between-gray-adams-and-pm-77-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.id, group_concat(t.tag separator ', ') as tags
  FROM movies
  JOIN tags t
    ON m.id = t.mid
 GROUP BY m.id
HAVING group_concat(t.tag) like '%DAWN%'
   and group_concat(t.tag) like '%OF%'
```

NOTE: Are the tags uppercase or lowercase, or mixed? In the above answer I assume they are all uppercase. You can use the UPPER or LOWER functions if the tags are not consistent, but they should be consistently upper or lowercase.

In the above query I used group_concat to show all tags on one row for each ID. That is a MYSQL function that will only work in MYSQL (you didn't mention what database you're using). If postgresql you would use string_agg, if Oracle you would use LISTAGG.

Comment: Hello! I must be awful at describing things. I have used that exact query before, but the issue is that each tag has its own row. Also, it's autocomplete, so if the user has not fully written out a word (tag), I need it to find all tags that start with what they have written.

Comment: @GrayAdams - Yes, you definitely are. I've already commented on this fact.

Comment: @GrayAdams I changed it back to like, which does make sense if the user is entering the criteria. The main problem is you are using OR vs. AND. Also your select list relative to the group by clause doesn't make sense. To fix that I selected ID and aggregated the tags with GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Though yours returned a comma delimited list, it also returns the exact same results as my query does (neglecting the GROUP BY clause I had in mine).

Comment: @GrayAdams can you try the 2nd query I posted w/ the HAVING clause? If that still returns the same result can you post sample data?

Answer (score 0):

What if you do something like this

```
select mid, 
group_concat(tag separator ' ') as fulltag
from tags
group by mid
```

the above query will get the entire tag list. say for `movie_id 1` if tags are `dawn,of,planet` then query result would be

```
1  dawn of planet
```

Then do a join like below. Also, if I consider that user enters tags as `dawn` and `of` together then before passing it to query, you can join them to make `dawn of` as a single string and then use a `LIKE` operator against it. That way you don't need to plumb multiple `LIKE` together.

So essentially, if user enters `dawn` as tag say `like 'dawn%'`.
if user enters `dawn` , `of` and `planet` as tag then join them to make `dawn of planet` and say `like 'dawn of planet%'`.

This joining the tags you can perform in your app code and then pass that as parameter to your query.

```
select m.name,
tab.fulltag
from movies m
join
(
select mid, 
group_concat(separator ' ') as fulltag
from tags
group by mid
) tab on m.id = tab.mid
where tab.tag LIKE 'Dawn Of%'
```

Comment: he can also use the having clause in the same query rather than join into it as an inline view

Comment: @Gray Adams, There a good catch to it. If you can join the search tags before passing to query as parameter then you can just limit to one `LIKE`. Check my answer.

Comment: I'll be able to try it out in a couple hours.

Comment: @Rahul Wouldn't doing this sort of concatenation be just one large unnecessary step? At this point, why not just do that LIKE statement directly on the movie's title in the movies table? Are tags still more efficient at this point?

Comment: @GrayAdams, It's either way round. If you join the search tags then perform only one LIKE operation else you do multiple. Talking about efficiency, I don't see any issue doing that and moreover, I would do the same to simplify my query.